# how to get function on fragment and use it in another class on Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, fragment, new-operator

trying to get String from my fragment and want to use it on my class but I keep getting error: getSampleData on a null object reference error. Can u help me?

my fragment

```
class sampleFragment : Fragment() {
    val sample= ""
    ...
    some codes r here
    ...

    fun getSampleData(): String {

    search_edit_text.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                                       count: Int, after: Int) {
        }
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                                   before: Int, count: Int) {
            sample= "${s}"
        }
    })
    return sample

}
```

This one is my other class

```
    class sampleAPIService()  {
    val getSample= sampleFragment()
    fun getSearchModel(): Single<search>{
    return api.getSearch(getSample.getSampleData())
    }
```

also when I Log.e to getSampleData() on fragment I can get user input correctly, so it's not null but I can't transfer it to my other class

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! `onTextChanged` will only run when text has changed, which is also when `sample` will be set. If you're calling `getSampleData()` for the first time then it can only return `""`.

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to say i have button which is doing search function and its call getSampleData where is my Log.e working on my fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getSampleData()` function doesn't make sense. Every time you call it, it's going to add another duplicate redundant listener to the EditText and then return whatever the current value of the EditText is (but only if the function has been called before and the EditText content has changed since then). You don't need a listener anyway if all you're doing is updating a property with the text. The current text can be directly retrieved from `editText.text.toString()`.

When your other class creates a new copy of your Fragment by calling its constructor, it is now working with some isolated, useless Fragment instance that has not been attached to the window and has no relation to the one that's actually showing on screen.

Overall, you need to design your classes differently so classes don't have to call functions on each other back and forth. It's very convoluted. For example, an API helper class should not have to know about any specific Fragment. This is the programming principle of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), or *encapsulation*.

The API helper class should be designed more like this, where it provides something based on an input that is directly related to what it's doing. A Fragment is not directly related to what an API would need to know to fetch something. The input should be a String in this case. For example:

```
class SampleAPIService()  {

    private val api = TODO()
    //...

    fun getSearch(searchText: String): Single<search>{
        return api.getSearch(searchText)
    }

}
```

A fragment should set its view listeners in `onViewCreated()`, so they are added only one time. Presumably, somewhere in your Fragment you have a button that initiates a search, so you should call your API from there.

```
class SampleFragment : Fragment() {
    val sample= ""
    private val sampleApiService = SampleApiService()
    // ...
    // some codes r here
    // ...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // ...

        someSearchButton.setOnClickListener {
            val searchResultSingle = sampleApiService.getSearch(search_edit_text.text.toString())
            // do something with result
        }
    }

}
```

By the way, all class names should start with a capital letter by convention or your code will be hard to read.

Comment: Thank you for information, i changed my codes like ur said but still searchResultSingle returns null, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: In my code above, it is not possible for `getSearch` to return null because the return type is non-nullable. If the API returned a null value, Kotlin intrinsic null check would crash the app before it could pass the null value along. Please edit your question to include your new code, and include the part where you check it and see that it's still null.

Comment: Sir finally I understand what u tried to mean and did it, I can perfectly take query now, and I can do search, I changed my codes like u told only changed click listener codes and its works fine thank you for your help

Comment: @Tenfour04: I have same problem and I tried to move content of my helper class ( e.g. `class Helper: Application(){ MyService.init(baseContext, "Hello!") }` to inside of the fragment as your above idea but it gives error and the app crashes. Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Tenfour04: Error is this: `(server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!`